# Why is heat current same in two different materials connected to each other?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

I recently learned in my physics class that the heat current at a boundary between two materials with different thermal conductivities is equal. Why is this so?

When these two materials are not connected to each other, they clearly will have different heat currents. How is there a ‘feedback’ that enables the heat current in the materials to increase/decrease.

Answer (score 1):

The equality arises from conservation of energy. The interface itself has no mass or spatial extent, so it cannot store energy. (It is essentially a plane.) Therefore, any energy entering from the right side, say, must exit from the left side. This includes heat flux. Does this make sense?

Comment: Can the same argument be used to explain why the heat current is the same everywhere in the conducting materials?

Comment: Not generally, because the intermediate material *can* store or provide energy. If I turn a light on in my room, for example, the heat flux through the walls doesn't change for a while. However, you could make this argument for a steady-state system because storage is precluded in this case.

Comment: Why is there a limit to the heat that can be absorbed by the material?

Comment: I don’t know what you’re referring to. If you’re asking why additional heat can’t be stored in the steady-state case, it’s because that storage would cause a temperature change or a phase change over time, which violates the condition of steady state.

Comment: Since there is heat flow, I’m asking about why the individual atoms cannot absorb this addition of energy. Why do they stop storing it after reaching a certain temperature?

Comment: Ah, I see. At a certain temperature, an equilibrium is reached because there's as much heat leaving as entering. Heat is lost very easily at high temperatures due to [Newton's law of cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling) and other mechanisms. So when we heat something, we often see the temperature initially rise quickly and then approach a plateau. [Heat transfer analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer) can be used to model this behavior.